# how to get a value from a char[]

Tags: c++, linux, scanf

however,thanks everyone who help me.
I want to get the VmRSS value from /proc/pid/status,below is the code

```
int main()
{ 
    const int PROCESS_MEMORY_FILE_LEN = 500;
    FILE *file;
    std::string path("/proc/4378/status");
    //path += boost::lexical_cast<std::string>( pid );
    //path += "/status";
    if(!(file = fopen(path.c_str(),"r")))
    {
        std::cout <<"open " << path<<"is failed " << std::endl;
        return float(-1);
    }
    char fileBuffer[PROCESS_MEMORY_FILE_LEN];
    memset(fileBuffer, 0, PROCESS_MEMORY_FILE_LEN);
    if(fread(fileBuffer, 1, PROCESS_MEMORY_FILE_LEN - 1, file) != (PROCESS_MEMORY_FILE_LEN - 1))
    {
        std::cout <<"fread /proc/pid/status is failed"<< std::endl;
        return float(-1);
    }

    fclose(file);

    unsigned long long memoryUsage = 0;
    int a = sscanf(fileBuffer,"VmRSS: %llu", &memoryUsage);
    std::cout << a << std::endl;
    std::cout << memoryUsage << std::endl;
}
```

at last,thanks

Comment: What is your exact problem? We won't step through your code.

Comment: What exactly are you asking? On Stack Overflow, one needs to ask specific questions or seek specific recommendations.

Comment: What process is that pid? If you want to get for the program you can't hardcode the pid as it will always change between runs.

Comment: sorry,I did not make it clear.the question is:I have a char[], data is "a: 1\n b: 2\n c: 3\n ..... n: n\n VmRSS: 4";I want to Get the VmRss's value. So,that is my problem.

Comment: Also, why are you mixing C++ with old stdio functions? And why are you returning floats from `main`?

Comment: then are just test codes, I just want to test sscanf function.yes, the codes are not stict,I will correct next time,thanking for your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comments: To find `VmRSS` within your char array use [C++ algorithms](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/) in combination with the C++ [string library](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/). Then you'll get the position of `VmRSS` and all you'll have to do is to retrieve the wanted result. With a little knowledge of the structure of these entries, this should be an easy task.

In addition to that it might be better to use [fstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iostream/fstream/) for reading directly into a string.